# Physical Calculator with Hyperreals and Multiple Dimensions?

Tags: complex-numbers, nonstandard-analysis, calculator

I'm just curious if there are any physical calculators out there that deal in the hyperreal number line or with multidimensional (i.e., complex) numbers.

It would be a fun project to do, but I'm curious if anyone has done one already.  Searches of this sort are difficult, as google always returns "calculators" on websites, not physical calculators.

Comment: Lots of pocket calculators for complex numbers. Nothing for hyperreals. Why would you want to?

Comment: Mostly just because it would be awesome.  "Does your calculator do infinity?"  "Yes, and even beyond!"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The hyperreal field is fairly large and not easily implementable on a computer but a smaller field called [Levi-Civita field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_field) has been implemented by a group around Shamseddine, see e.g.,

> Shamseddine, Khodr. Analysis on the Levi-Civita field and computational applications. Appl. Math. Comput.  255  (2015), 44–57.

The implementation is accessible [here](http://www.bt.pa.msu.edu/index_cosy.htm).

The Levi-Civita non-Archimedean field is probably sufficient for most applications that a calculator user may be interested in.

Comment: This is exactly what I was imagining.  In what way is this smaller than the hyperreals?

Comment: Can the Levi-Civita field be embedded into the hyperreals, or be represented as quotient of it?

Comment: @johnnyb Cardinality, probably.

Comment: What is known about the natural numbers in this system? What axioms do they satisfy? (I don't think they satisfy the Peano axioms.)

Comment: Found this guy as well - http://www.lightandmatter.com/calc/inf/

Comment: @PyRulez, somebody who wants to use the calculator for calculations with infinitesimals is not necessarily concerned with Peano Axioms.

Answer (score 1):

Eh, part of the problem is that you'd have to be able to do computations with its set of natural numbers, which [in general is impossible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tennenbaum%27s_theorem).

That being said, I bet you could work in a proof system axiomatically. You could also use a regular computer algebra, and then use the [transfer principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfer_principle#Transfer_principle_for_the_hyperreals).

(In particular, I imagine something like mathematica or the wolfram language, argumented with a "variable" $H$, along with assumed facts "$H \ge 0$", "$H \ge 1$", "$H \ge 2$", $\dots$ would be pretty powerful.)

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking of.  I think it could be pretty epic.